# startAfter function always display the same data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I'm beginner to firestore.
My query always give the same data independently of the value i pass into startAfter() function.

here's code:

```
    const fetchMore = async () => {
        const q = query(
            collection(db, 'chat-messages'),
            orderBy('createdAt', 'asc'),
            startAfter(23),
            limit(5),
        );

        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q)

        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(doc.data())
        })
    }
```

Thanks for reading and helping!
Have a nice day

[image]

here's the console.log

Comment: That seems unexpected. Can you change the code to execute two queries with different values for `startAfter` and then show us the updated code and the `console.log` output that you get?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, I can. I edited the post and added the photo of console.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what type the data in your `startAt` field is, but I guess it's a date or a Firestore `Timestamp`.

Pagination in Firestore is not based on numeric offsets, as you may be used to from other databases, but instead is based on so-called cursor objects: knowing the values and/or ID of the document you want to start after.

So you'll need to pass in the timestamp that you want to start after, not the number of documents you want to skip. So for example, to get all documents with a `createdAt` after now, you could do:

```
startAfter(Timestamp.now())
```

For more on this way of pagination, see the documentation on [paginating data with query cursors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors).

Comment: To add to this, the startAfter value is refering to value of the field that is used inside of `orderBy` function. In authors example it is `createdAt` field as specified in documentation's usage examples:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors

Also make sure the types are matching. If you used number for field's value then use the same type for `startAfter` value also.